# Flutter http_auth headers contain "carrier return" and "new line" characters (\r\n)

Tags: flutter, http-headers, flutter-dependencies

I am currently experimenting with flutter and tried to use http package. When I request a resource, which requires an authorization header (Authorization: Basic ) I create my request as follows:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void request() {
    http.get('http://<my_url>', headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic <hash>'}).then( (resp) {
       print('response status: ${resp.statusCode} ${resp.reasonPhrase}');
    }
}
```

While executing this request, I was watching the request sent over Wireshark and noticed, that it contains carrier-return (\r) and new-line (\n) characters at the end:
[Snapshot of Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na9hl.png)

After invoking my request function, I get a 401 Unauthorized message in my print statement. When I invoke the same request in Postman, everything is fine.

I assume, that my authentication failed, because of these characters (\r\n) at the end of each header entry. Can anyone help me with it or am I doing something wrong?

PS.: I have also tried the http_auth package but it also failed.

```
import 'package:http_auth/http_auth.dart' as http_auth;

void request(String user, String password) {
    http_auth.BasicAuthClient(user, password).get('http://<my_url>', headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic <hash>'}).then( (resp) {
       print('response status: ${resp.statusCode} ${resp.reasonPhrase}');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `\r\n` characters are meant to be there. They are the line separators between the headers. If you packet capture the wire bytes from `curl --user foo:bar www.dart.dev` you will see exactly the same thing.

You will notice that Dart has lower-cased the header name to `authorization` as is perfectly valid per the RFC. However, this sometimes catches out some servers that (incorrectly) treat the header names case sensitively.

Try your postman again (or a curl with a manually-created, lower-case header) with `authorization`. If the server doesn't accept that, contact the server maintainer.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. You're right. The server actually does NOT accept the lower case "authorization". I'll try to debug it on that end. Thanks ^^